# Reduce or group Database service calls into batch

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have some functional units of transactional work within service(s) which involved multiple calls to different DAOs (using jdbcTemplate or NamedJdbcTemplate) that return sequence generated IDs to run the next select/insert or run some void insertion in the order of calls.  Each DAO call represents a sql statement which will require a call to the Database.  For example

```
@Transactional
public void create() {
    playerService.findByUserName(player.getPlayerId());
    roleService.insertRoleForPlayer(player.getId(), ROLE_MANAGER);
    leagueScoringService.createLeagueScoringForLeague(leagueScoring);
    leagueService.insertPlayerLeague(player, code);
    Standing playerStanding = new Standing();
    playerStanding.setPlayerId(player.getId());
    playerStanding.setPlayerUserName(player.getPlayerId());
    playerStanding.setLeagueId(leagueId);
    standingService.insertStandings(ImmutableList.of(playerStanding));
}
```

Preferably I want to batch up the calls or ensure they all get executed together on the DB.  Note I do not use hibernate and I don't want to either.  What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/unit-of-work) would help. Have never used it - but Unit of Work Design Pattern immediately sprang to mind.

Comment: That's alright if it's the same underlying object in that example student.  The implementation of iunitofwork works off a single entity.  I'm sure there has to be a smarter more efficient way to do this.  Adding in the fact that I've thought about caching IDs but I don't like the idea of that either

Comment: Here's a C# equivalent - the code shows more than one table.. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/unit-of-work-in-repository-pattern/  Uses UoW + Repository to deal with multiple entities.